# Passing a value from java to a named parameter in an oracle statement

Tags: sql, oracle, java-8, oracle11gr2

I'm trying to pass an array of strings to a named parameter of a prepared statement:

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM FOOBAR
WHERE HOSTID IN (:hostIds)
ORDER BY NAME;
```

The type of *HOSTID* is *Number*.

The value I want to pass is saved as string in my database, e. g.: '1, 3, 37'.
I've already tried various approaches but I couldn't make it work yet.

First: Passing this value as it is.
Problem: Works fine with one value ('1'), but won't work with multiple values since oracle interprets it as one value ('1, 3') -> 1.3 (?)

Second: Create a collection, build an java.sql.Array and pass it.
Problem: Inconsistent datatypes :( I've created a collection like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR2_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2;
```

And tried to build an array and use

```
statement.setArrayAtName("hostIds", value);
```

But this didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by myself. I changed my statement to:

```
SELECT *
FROM FOOBAR
WHERE to_char(HOSTID) IN
      (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(:hostIds, '[^,]+', 1, level))
       FROM dual
       CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:hostIds, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY NAME;
```